# Why won't my model's accuracy exceed .508 despite loss decreasing, when I train it in TFJS?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

This post is aptly titled: my stock prediction model's accuracy just won't go past 0.5088282227516174 despite loss decreasing. I have tried so many different things, such as:

- Increasing batch size
- Decreasing batch size
- Decreasing learning rate
- Changing optimizer back and forth between adam, rmsprop, and sgd.
- Using literally the same exact code that worked very well for one of my other projects (iris dataset), except with the changed variables and names.
- Changing units
- Adding layers
- Switching between ReLu, Sigmoid, and Softmax for the layers

For every one of these, I either get no results, as in "NaN" for the loss or 0 for the loss and accuracy; or if it does work, the loss goes down gradually, but the accuracy stays the same. Even though I used the same code format and outline for the Iris project--to classify between setosa, versicolor, and virginica--which worked flawlessly, this is not the case despite datasets being of relatively similar format.

The main premise of this is to predict if the stock price, when given the inputs of: opening and closing price, high and low price of the day, volume, and the percent change increase of SPY.
The label is a classifier of whether or not it gained or lost value the next day from that date, with the classifiers being "profit," or "loss." A sample of the data CSV is shown below:

```
next_day_inc,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,spy_inc
profit,1.761,1.761,1.674,1.707,4137000.000,-0.258
```

Here is my program code, which worked flawlessly with the iris classification dataset:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Iris</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>

</head>
<script>
    async function run() {
        const csvUrl = 'SOXLcateg.csv';
        const trainingData = tf.data.csv(csvUrl, {
            columnConfigs: {
                next_day_inc: {
                    isLabel: true
                }
            }
        });
        const convertedData = trainingData.map(({ xs, ys }) => {
            const labels = [
                ys.next_day_inc == "profit" ? 1 : 0,
                ys.next_day_inc == "loss" ? 1 : 0]
            return { xs: Object.values(xs), ys: Object.values(labels) };
        }).batch(300);
        const numOfFeatures = (await trainingData.columnNames()).length - 1;

        const model = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({
            inputShape: [numOfFeatures],
            activation: "sigmoid", units: 5
        }));
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({ activation: "softmax", units: 2 }));
        model.compile({
            loss: "binaryCrossentropy",
            optimizer: tf.train.adam(0.0006),
            metrics: "accuracy"
        })
        await model.fitDataset(
            convertedData,
            {
                shuffle: true,
                epochs: 50,
                callbacks: {
                    onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
                        console.log("E: " + epoch + " Loss: " + logs.loss + " Accuracy: " + logs.acc);
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        const testVal = tf.tensor2d([2.383,2.619,2.383,2.599,15642000.000,0.102], [1, 6]);
        const prediction = model.predict(testVal);
        const pIndex = tf.argMax(prediction, axis = 1).dataSync();
        const classNames = ["Profit", "Loss"];
        alert(classNames[pIndex]);
        // await model.save("downloads://model");
    }
    run();
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Any time it does work, the accuracy spikes from whatever it originally is to 0.5088282227516174 and stays that way for the rest of the training, while the loss gradually gets smaller. If anyone can help me on this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Edit: just wanted to say, I'm a noob at this so please excuse my naivety.
Edit 2: Here is the link to the CSV: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FV4zxVejTZz9GcjnG6WjIhuXShG3q93_/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

I updated the use of the strict equality check and since you are one-hot encoding the target variables you would need to use the `categoricalCrossentropy` loss function.

```
const convertedData = trainingData
  .map(({ xs, ys }) => {
    const labels = [
      ys.next_day_inc === "profit" ? 1 : 0,
      ys.next_day_inc === "loss" ? 1 : 0,
    ];
    return { xs: Object.values(xs), ys: Object.values(labels) };
  })
  .batch(32);
const numOfFeatures = (await trainingData.columnNames()).length - 1;

const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(
  tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [numOfFeatures],
    activation: "sigmoid",
    units: 5,
  })
);
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ activation: "softmax", units: 2 }));
model.compile({
  loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
  optimizer: tf.train.adam(0.001),
  metrics: "accuracy",
});
await model.fitDataset(convertedData, {
  shuffle: true,
  epochs: 50,
  callbacks: {
    onEpochEnd: async (epoch, logs) => {
      console.log(
        "E: " + epoch + " Loss: " + logs.loss + " Accuracy: " + logs.acc
      );
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, it still is stuck at at .508... or .492... and the loss just doesn't change at all after applying your changes. Do you have anymore suggestions? Thank you

Comment: @Anon include the csv file so I can try some other things

Comment: Here is a google drive link to the CSV: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FV4zxVejTZz9GcjnG6WjIhuXShG3q93_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm sorry, that didn't work either.  It did fix the problem of the loss not changing, though. Thank you so much for your time in this, may peace be upon you!  Do you think if I rescale the data in the CSV file, i.e. dividing them by something like 100000 to make them smaller, it will perhaps work? And maybe even remove/redo some of that data, into a more relative format like percentage increase rather than closing price and opening price? If you have any other suggestions, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @Anon scaling the numeric values to a range between 0 and 1 might help for minute gains in accuracy(no guarantee though), when you have an accuracy of 0.5 for a binary classification task it means the model is making random guesses which shows a more serious issue is at hand. I will need to try running the code with the data myself to debug it.

Comment: Please feel free to run it with the data! The original post has all the code, and the CSV I linked is all the data I used for this project. I really appreciate your help, thanks so much!